# NodeJS what is the fastest currency rounding method?

Tags: node.js, rounding

Is there any faster way to round numbers into two decimal places then, this method (currency rounding)?

```
function Round(number) {
  return (Math.round(number * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);
}
```

Comment: It depends. Do you need your returned value to be a String or a Number? Because if you only need it to be a Number, the "toFixed" part is not necessary.

Comment: FYI, currency calculations should never be done with floating point numbers because of the problem that some floating point numbers cannot be accurately represented in the floating point format that Javascript uses.  Accurate currency can be done with an integer number of cents and then only add a decimal for display in dollars/cents.

Answer (score 0):

We´re using `Number(Math.round(totalAmount + 'e' + 2) + 'e-' + 2)` for any currency rounding...
`.toFixed(2)` is not safe for floats...